# Alternative for Wireshark for USB packet sniffing

Tags: tools, usb, sniffing, wireshark

I'm looking for alternative for Wireshark, with this requirements:

- Cross-platform (Windows and Linux)
- USB packet sniffing
- Easy creation of dissectors

Wireshark is great, but Lua API for writing dissectors miss some critical features, like conversations (linking request and response packets).

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Wait, why do you claim these are missing from the Lua interface? I know they're unwieldy and generally these dissectors tend to be slow. Perhaps I am misunderstanding. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The fact they're slow isn't that bad, I'm using Lua API because of flexibility and development speed, I don't need to have source code of Wireshark and compile it everytime I make small change. I sent the [question](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/13396/link-request-and-response-packets-in-lua-dissector/) on Wireshark QA, but without reply, seem that there isn't solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about software recommendation, not reverse-engineering.

Comment: @peterferrie but it's software recommendation for a reverse-engineering application, so why this should be offtopic?